# Combine rows with same datetime while keeping columns intact

Tags: python-3.x, pandas

new to Python and coding. I'm struggling on how I could approach this.

I have a dataframe formatted as such:

```
Timestamp      A     B     C
00:00:00      NaN   NaN    15.67
00:00:00      NaN   1.66   NaN
00:00:00      95.30 NaN    NaN
00:10:00      NaN   NaN    5.44
00:10:00      NaN   22.67  NaN
00:10:00      96.55 NaN    NaN
```

and I want to combine the rows with the same timestamp while keeping the data in their respective columns as such:

```
Timestamp      A     B     C
00:00:00      95.30   1.66    15.67
00:10:00      96.55   22.67    5.44
```

I'm thinking of iterating through each row and removing the NaN's and replacing it with the value below it, but I don't know if that would be consistent with keeping the same Timestamps.

Thanks!

Comment: As of now, this should work `df.groupby('Timestamp').first()`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

#### If `Timestamp` is the index

```
               A      B      C
Timestamp                     
00:00:00     NaN    NaN  15.67
00:00:00     NaN   1.66    NaN
00:00:00   95.30    NaN    NaN
00:10:00     NaN    NaN   5.44
00:10:00     NaN  22.67    NaN
00:10:00   96.55    NaN    NaN
```

Then

```
df.groupby('Timestamp').first()

               A      B      C
Timestamp                     
00:00:00   95.30   1.66  15.67
00:10:00   96.55  22.67   5.44
​
```

---

#### If `Timestamp` is a column

```
  Timestamp      A      B      C
0  00:00:00    NaN    NaN  15.67
1  00:00:00    NaN   1.66    NaN
2  00:00:00  95.30    NaN    NaN
3  00:10:00    NaN    NaN   5.44
4  00:10:00    NaN  22.67    NaN
5  00:10:00  96.55    NaN    NaN
```

Then

```
df.groupby('Timestamp', as_index=False).first()

  Timestamp      A      B      C
0  00:00:00  95.30   1.66  15.67
1  00:10:00  96.55  22.67   5.44
```

Comment: Well that was a lot more simple than I thought. Thank you so much! :)